# How to include dojo correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I would like to included dojo files download to my machine, how to do so?
I kept getting "dojo is not defined" in the Error Console and the webpage does not show up the same as the original. What am I missing out?

The original ones had these:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js"
        djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dojox.layout.FloatingPane");
        dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"
        />
<style type="text/css">
        @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojox/layout/resources/FloatingPane.css";
        @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojox/layout/resources/ResizeHandle.css";
 </style>
```

I didn't see any "dojo.xd.js" file in my downloaded dojo folder, so I changed them to these:

```
<script src="C:/Users/Yeeen/Desktop/WebpageTest/js/src/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js"
        djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dojox.layout.FloatingPane");
        dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:/Users/Yeeen/Desktop/WebpageTest/js/src/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"
        />
<style type="text/css">
        @import "C:/Users/Yeeen/Desktop/WebpageTest/js/src/dojox/layout/resources/FloatingPane.css";
        @import "C:/Users/Yeeen/Desktop/WebpageTest/js/src/dojox/layout/resources/ResizeHandle.css";
 </style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this would directly fix your problem but you should try installing a webserver in your machine so that you can point to `http://localhost/something` instead of using a `file://` address. Some browsers don't allow AJAX from a `file://` origin and that can be annoying (and might mess up the module system)

As for the immediate problem, I am not sure browsers handle that `C:` in the address very well. Have you tried using relative filepaths instead?

Comment: +1'd for "use a webserver" and the no-XHR-from-file:// tip.  This snags *so* many people who download Dojo to try it.